# jQuery script works just on first click. Why?

Tags: jquery

I've got this script and it only works on first click. It should change content in a single  tag depending on checked radio button.

```
$(function(){
    $(".reference").click(function()
    {
            var chosenTheme = $(".reference input").val(); 
            $(".template td:first-child").text("Some text - " + chosenTheme);
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea why doesn't the content change on second and more clicks?

Comment: use `var chosenTheme = $(this).find("input").val(); `

Comment: Probably because the HTML that listens to the event is wiped out during the process.

Comment: you need to show more information and explain better... but you probably are looking for something like this instead `var chosenTheme = $(this).children('input').val();`

Comment: how you know it's not working on second click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used** `var chosenTheme = $(this).find("input").val();`

**instead of**  `var chosenTheme = $(".reference input").val();`

And It's working now! Thank you all.